# Sort list of floats, ints, or strings

Tags: elm

I'm trying to make a sortable table that takes different kinds of data. Before rendering it as a grid, I convert all of the data to Strings (for the view). However, elm cannot properly sort a list of floats or ints converted to strings (you end up with something like 1, 1001, 10.03, 21, 3.4, ...).
I've had the idea to create a union type,

```
type ColType
    = StrCol String
    | IntCol String
    | FloatCol String
    | BoolCol String
```

However, at some point I need to convert back to String, if it is a StrCol, or Int if an IntCol, etc., and then sort; but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a function that converts the contents of each tag to strings:

```elm
colTypeToString : ColType -> String
colTypeToString colType =
    case colType of
        StrCol x -> toString x
        IntCol x -> toString x
        FloatCol x -> toString x
        BoolCol x -> toString x
```

Comment: But then I'm back to the original problem; if I first convert ints or floats to strings, then the sort doesn't return the correct result. I need to convert from ColType to String, if it's a StrCol, or to Int, if it's an IntCol, then sort, then convert back to ColType, then to String. 
Or if there's another way, feel free to suggest. The important thing is, I need to check whether the values in a dictionary were once-upon-a-time-ago an Int or String, then sort it as a list of Strings OR Ints, then render the Dict in a table as String fields.

Comment: The data should only be converted to a string in your `view` function, and the data should already be sorted by then. Are you instead storing the values as string for display in your model? If you can add more context to the question (code snippets of where and when sorting happens in relation to rendering), I could better understand the problem area.

Comment: I store the data as a list of dictionaries, and the fields must all have the same type. I  make all kinds of modifications to the List Dict, sorting is just one. I suppose I could rewrite those functions to instead modify a list of records, and the convert the list of records to a list of dict each time the view is rendered...

Comment: Please add some more code for context to the question. It doesn't sound like you have to move from your list of dictionaries, I just think you need to delay converting to a string until the time when you're writing the value of the column in the view. It just sounds like you're converting to string too early, when there is still type-specific functionality still needed.

Comment: Or converting to a string for display only and not carrying around information that could be useful for sorting such a the original value or a sortable string value such as one that is zero padded for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which you could try.

I used `Dict` to represent record of data where
`Value` can be either `Float` or `String`, instead
of defining `ColType` (your suggestion).
(It is easy to extend to support other `comparable` types.)

```elm
-- MODEL
type alias Model =
  { rows : List Row
  , cols : List String
  , sortkey : Maybe String
  }

type alias Row = Dict.Dict String Value
createRow : String -> Float -> Row
createRow name val = Dict.fromList
  [ ("name", StrValue name)
  , ("value", FloatValue val)
  ]

type Value
  = StrValue String
  | FloatValue Float

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  let
    rows =
      [ createRow "A" 1.5
      , createRow "B" 0.5
      ]
    cols = ["name", "value"]
    sortkey = Nothing
  in (Model rows cols sortkey, Cmd.none)

-- VIEW
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
    renderRow cols row = tr [] <| List.map (renderValue row) cols
    renderValue row key = case (Dict.get key row) of
      Just (StrValue str) -> td [] [text str]
      Just (FloatValue num) -> td [] [text <| toString num]
      _ -> td [] [text "-"]
    renderHeaders cols = tr []
      <| List.map renderHeaderName model.cols
    renderHeaderName colname =
      th [ onClick (Sort colname) ]
        <| if Just colname == model.sortkey
           then [ text <| colname ++ "*" ]
           else [ text colname ]
  in
    table []
      <| [ renderHeaders model.cols ]
      ++ List.map (renderRow model.cols) model.rows

-- UPDATE
type Msg
  = Sort String

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Sort name ->
      let
        sortedRows = List.sortWith compareVal model.rows
        compareVal a b = case (Dict.get name a, Dict.get name b) of
          (Just (StrValue sa), Just (StrValue sb)) -> compare sa sb
          (Just (FloatValue na), Just (FloatValue nb)) -> compare na nb
          _ -> EQ
      in ({ model | rows = sortedRows, sortkey = Just name }, Cmd.none)
```